# Does deleting a file removes all replication files as well in hdfs

Tags: hdfs

Does deleting a file removes all replication files as well in hdfs?

Is trash the only way to recover deleted files from hdfs?

Replication factor is only used internal by framework for fault tolerance? Any network or other failures happen?

I am just trying to relate deleting a file, recovery from trash, replication factor in HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

A file in HDFS can be removed using rmr command. However, HDFS supports Trash feature which helps to recover files in case of accidental deletion of data. When the Trash feature is enabled, a file is moved to the `.Trash` folder under the user's HDFS directory.

However, internally how it works is that HDFS will just create **metadata** in the trash folder to identity the file and the associated block information that needs to be deleted once the `fs.trash.interval` time interval is complete after the file is deleted . The actual file contents i.e. the replicated blocks of the file are still present on the original data nodes where they were present before the delete operation.

If the user wants to recover the deleted file, all that is done is delete the metadata information from the `.Trash` folder and the original data is anyways lying on the datanodes as usual.

To answer your query, deleting a file doesn't delete the file contents and its blocks from the datanodes.

Comment: Thanks. but my problem is my trash is rolled and i could not see files in it, as i did not set the trash time in the conf. SO wondering if we can recover still. So my question is when trash is not set and a file is deleted after some time, all data is lost(all replicas?)